# Attribute Value Read?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

Currently im trying to read a XML attribute with no sucess, so far what i got is :

```
        XmlDocument _doc = new XmlDocument();
        _doc.LoadXml(@"<DATA jsonclass=""array"">
        <ROW id=""1"">
          <D n=""697""/>
          <D n=""2601"">10815</D>
          <D n=""3242""/>
          <D n=""3243"">2017-03-15 00:00:00.0</D>
          <D n=""3245"">+</D>
          <D n=""3274""/>
          <D n=""4895"">USD</D>
        </ROW>
        <ROW id=""1"">
          <D n=""697""/>
          <D n=""2601"">10816</D>
          <D n=""3242""/>
          <D n=""3243"">2017-03-15 00:00:00.0</D>
          <D n=""3245"">+</D>
          <D n=""3274""/>
          <D n=""4895"">USD</D>
        </ROW>
      </DATA>");


        XmlNodeList elemLista = _doc.GetElementsByTagName("D");
        for (int i = 0; i < elemLista.Count; i++)
        {
            string attrVal = elemLista[i].Attributes["n"].Value;

            //this is returnig 2601 and Im looking for **10816**
            Console.WriteLine(attrVal);

            //      Req.RequestAllPOAvailable();`



        }
    }
```

I'm expecting to get 10815 and 10816, but the results is the same.... the output still  2601, what im doing wrong? thanks for your help

Comment: you are getting the value of attribute `n` and it's returning the value of attribute `n`. I don't see what is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you're getting 2601 is that you're getting the value of the n attribute you need to get the inner text of the elment:

```
 XmlDocument _doc = new XmlDocument();
        _doc.LoadXml(@"<DATA jsonclass=""array"">
        <ROW id=""1"">
          <D n=""697""/>
          <D n=""2601"">10815</D>
          <D n=""3242""/>
          <D n=""3243"">2017-03-15 00:00:00.0</D>
          <D n=""3245"">+</D>
          <D n=""3274""/>
          <D n=""4895"">USD</D>
        </ROW>
        <ROW id=""1"">
          <D n=""697""/>
          <D n=""2601"">10816</D>
          <D n=""3242""/>
          <D n=""3243"">2017-03-15 00:00:00.0</D>
          <D n=""3245"">+</D>
          <D n=""3274""/>
          <D n=""4895"">USD</D>
        </ROW>
      </DATA>");


        XmlNodeList elemLista = _doc.GetElementsByTagName("D");
        for (int i = 0; i < elemLista.Count; i++)
        {
            string attrVal = elemLista[i].InnerText;

            //this is returnig 2601 and Im looking for **10816**
            Console.WriteLine(attrVal);

            //      Req.RequestAllPOAvailable();`



        }
```

Comment: Oh, my.... Thanks !!!